# 4k Monitor doesn't give me the option for 4k resolution

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, gpu

I have an Acer XR341CK 4k monitor and a XFX Radeon r9 280x GPU. I have my monitor hooked up with an HDMI cable from the monitor to an adapter to go to a mini Display Port on my GPU. For some reason when I try to change the resolution on my monitor in order to take advantage of the full 4k, I only have the option to go to 1920x1080. I have no idea why I don't have the option to go to 4k.

Comment: Don't use an HDMI cable or connector. Use displayport all the way through.

Comment: @Davidschwartz I will get a cable for it and I'll update the post. I appreciate your input.